# I had the following 'heading-font'

Tags: css, sass, ruby-on-rails-5, bootstrap-sass

I had the following **error**:
  'heading-font'

ul.quicklinks {

```
@include heading-font; //error in thisline: Undefined mixin 'heading-font'
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a mixin before importing it **first** in any scss file.

```scss
@import 'mixins.scss'; /* imports the SCSS file with the mixin */

ul.quicklinks {
    font-size: 90%;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: none;
    @include heading-font; /* using the mixin */
}
```